# How to combine switchMap with combineLatest

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I need to combine UserRole from RealtimeDatabase and User from FirebaseAuth. How do I combine these two queries, one of which is based on the other? The following code allows you to download a single file or two files simultaneously.

```
from(this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password))
      .pipe(
        switchMap((result: any) => this.getUserRole(result.user.uid)),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(console.warn);
```

or

```
combineLatest([x1, this.getUserRole('8OKFSRBeZ3dY4ecQVn8AyJHBQim2')])
  .pipe(tap(console.warn))
.subscribe();
```

Comment: You want to know the best approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work for you? Note: combineLatest may be not the best for the case, you can try frokJoin.

```
from(this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password))
    .pipe(
        switchMap((result: any) => combineLatest(of(result.user), this.getUserRole(result.user.uid))),
    )
    .subscribe(console.warn);
```